# Flutter deactivate screen timeout

Tags: dart, flutter

How to deactivate screen timeout in Flutter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using this Flutter package : https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/screen

On Android you will have to add a new permission on your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

**Install de plugin**

Add this dependency in your `pubspec.yaml` file

```
screen: ^0.0.3
```

And use it in your dart files:

```
import 'package:screen/screen.dart';

// Prevent screen from going into sleep mode:
Screen.keepOn(true);
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfect on Android! <br /> Is is also preventing IOS to turn off the screen? The plugin description is writing it is working on ios. I was not able to test this until now because i am still setting up my enviroment to compile ios...